# Google Tag Manager Carousel Links

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm new to GTM and am trying to capture "next" and "prev" events on multiple carousels throughout my site.

My HTML.

```
<div id="hero1">
  //... slides
  <div class="slide-next"></div>
  <div class="slide-prev"></div>
</div>   

<div id="hero2">
  //... slides
  <div class="slide-next"></div>
  <div class="slide-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Anytime I click a `div` with class `slide-next` (and also `slide-prev`), I'd like to capture the following:

**Category:** Carousel button

**Action:** Click - Next (or prev)

**Label:** Hero1

Is there a way to do this in Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Have you tried the click on Link example from the docs? https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en

Comment: Yes, but I have multiple carousels and I'd like to grab specific information about which one a user was clicking around. When I use a click listener, it only grabs the <div> I clicked, and not it's parent ID.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new Data Layer Variable macro with gtm.element.parentElement.id as Variable Name.
- Create another Data Layer Variable macro with gtm.element.className as Variable Name.
- Create a new rule where event equals gtm.linkClick and your previously created macro -first one- starts with hero
- Create a new UA Tag, **Type:** Event, **Category:** Carousel, **Action:** macro with gtm.element.className, **Label:** macro with gtm.element.parentElement.id. Use the previous rule to fire this tag.

Of course, you will need also a click listener tag.